# "Audit log reports" link is missing inside my sharepoint enterprise wiki site collection's site settings

Tags: 2013, site-collection, administration, site, auditing

I have a sharepoint server 2013 on-premises. ad i have 2 site collections of these types:-

1. Enterprise wiki site collection.
2. Team site collection, which have the publishing features enabled at the site collection level and at the site level.

now i want to enable the audit logs reporting, to be able to track the modifications on these site collections.

now on the Team site collection i got these 2 links (one to configure the reporting while the other to view/download the report)

[image]

but inside my enterprise wiki site collection, the second link "Audit log reports" is missing:-
[image]

But when i try to manually navigate to the link using `http://servername/sitecollectionurl/_layouts/15/Reporting.aspx?Category=Auditing`, i am able to access the "Audit log reports" for the enterprise wiki site collection.. but not sure why inside the UI the "Audit log reports" is missing?? does this mean that i should not use this feature on enterprise wiki site collections? or it is an issue with the UI ?
Regards

Comment: Is the Site Collection Feature named "Reporting" turned on?

Comment: @TrevorSeward  No seems inside the enterprise wiki the "Reporting" site collection feature is not enabled. so do i need to enable it to show the “Audit log reports” link? if the answer is Yes, then as i mentioned currently i can manually navigate to the “Audit log reports” page using this url `http://servername/sitecollectionurl/_layouts/15/Reporting.aspx?Category=Auditing`. so what is the purpose of enabling the "Reporting" site collection feature? to only show the “Audit log reports” link? as seems without enabling it the reporting page is there, but the “Audit log reports” link is missing!!

Comment: @TrevorSeward can you please advice on my above comment?

Comment: Did you find answers for this question ?